# What is the Limitation of Training data set -Uima Ruta

Tags: machine-learning, uima, ruta

[image: Error Report]In TextRuler view, Is there any limitation for the Number of Input in Training Data.Because It's taking too much time.Sometimes it's generating the rules orelse it's showing some GC overhead limit.

If I try to use the script which are generated by the algorithms,It shows some error.

ERROR:

```
Error in KEP,  line 160, "SCRIPT": found no viable alternative
```

Generated Script:

```
SCRIPTSTART{->MARKONCE(SCRIPT,1,3)} ANY*? SCRIPTEND;
SCRIPTSTART{IS(SCRIPTEND)->MARKONCE(SCRIPT)} ;
```

Answer (score 0):

About the error:

The error indicates that SCRIPT is not known. Is the type SCRIPT declared?
It is possible that the resulting rules are just rules and that you need to add imports in order to build a correct script. What is the content of line 160?

About TextRuler in general:

The framework was created in order to support the user during rule engineering. It is not a framework optimized for the common supervised machine learning. Thus, it is not optimized for runtime and memory usage.

The algorithms create rules for each example and try to get a good coverage. Thus, the more examples, the longer the algorithm will take.

The memory usage should not be so high. This is probably something that can be fixed, but right now there is nothing one can do about it.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*

Comment: The content of line 160 is SCRIPTSTART{->MARKONCE(SCRIPT,1,3)} ANY*? SCRIPTEND;
SCRIPTSTART{IS(SCRIPTEND)->MARKONCE(SCRIPT)} ;which is generated from Kep algorithm.I tried to run the resulting rule generated by the kep algorithm.Then only I received the above error.

Comment: What imports I need to add to build a correct script?

Comment: This depends on your configuration. Normally, you need the script you specified in `Preprocess script` int he TextRuler view. I assume that it is the script where you declared SCRIPT.

Comment: Is it in parameter configuration.

Comment: You can add a line like `SCRIPT my.package.PreprocessScript;`

Comment: Normally, you would maybe create a new script for the learnt rules, e.g., called `Induced.ruta`. You need to import the type system in this script, so that the types are resolved

Comment: The Script  generated from Kep algorithm already contains line like SCRIPT my.package.PreprocessScript;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124684/discussion-between-sugunalakshmi-g-and-peter-kluegl).

Comment: How can I promote my script to the next level.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Still I'm receiving the above issue.
The Script generated from Kep algorithm already contains line like SCRIPT my.package.PreprocessScript;

Comment: When I use TEXTRULER ,I feel that I didnt get good coverage.How does it works. Whether I'm using it in a correct way.

Comment: I'm keeps on changing my script for any new occurrence.So How to train my Data (will clearTK help in this situation or any other machine learning thing is available).